# How to interpret string variable with two dollar sign for curl on shell script?

Tags: shell, variables, curl, dollar-sign

I have a problem on running curl command on shell script. I have a string variable with two dollar sign character, show as below example:

```
local auth="$3xLxLBcsKv$zY59kBuIpKeG4q1526phJ9"
```

I need pass this variable to curl command. Like below is my write but not work:

```
curl --connect-timeout 2 -H 'Extender-Auth: $auth' https://192.168.5.1/1/
```

But the writing is wrong on shell script. Can someone help me how to modify the writing make it work on shell script?

Thank for your help!

Make curl can work with above option and value.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.warp.dev/terminus/curl-basic-auth

Comment: The value of auth variable is random not hard code, I get it from other cli

Comment: If you type `echo "$auth"` and `echo "${auth//\$/\\$}"` do you get any output?

Comment: `a='$RANDOM'; echo "$a"; b="$RANDOM"; echo "$b"; echo '$c'`

Comment: If you type echo "$auth" and echo "${auth//\$/\\$}" do you get any output? 
Hi jared_mamrot, I try this on curl but get nothing output. I use -x debug it still show ${auth//\$/\\$} not the real value. So it seem still string not variable to curl cli

Comment: I don't see two $ signs in your code. Note also that `$auth` won't be expanded in your curl invocation. Aside from this, your definition of `auth` will most likely set it to the null string.

Answer (score 0):

With double quote - bash will try to perform variable substitution in the enclosed string:

```
local auth="$3xLxLBcsKv$zY59kBuIpKeG4q1526phJ9"
```

Will try to expand "$3", and "$zY59kBuIpKeG4q1526phJ". Most likely second is empty, and first may be anything.

Try using the single quote, which does not perform substitution:

```
local auth='$3xLxLBcsKv$zY59kBuIpKeG4q1526phJ9'

curl --connect-timeout 2 -H "Extender-Auth: $auth" https://192.168.5.1/1/
```

Comment: Hi, I had added comment above. The auth variable is from cli and it is ramdon not hard code. Thx!

Comment: The important, uncommented, solution in this answer is to use **double quotes** in the curl command so the $auth variable can be exanded